# Is this a correct unraveling of the notion of a topological embedding?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote topological spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$ denote a continuous mapping. Then $f$ is an embedding iff the corestriction $X \rightarrow f(X)$ is a homeomorphism. However this is quite a heavily packaged definition and I can imagine that it would sometimes be desirable to have a more direct characterization. I've thought about it a bit and I think that $f$ is an embedding iff firstly it is injective, and secondly we have that for all $U \subseteq Y$, if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open, then there exists an open set $V \subseteq Y$ such that $U \cap \mathrm{img}(f) = V \cap \mathrm{img}(f).$

> **Question.** Is this a correct 'unpacking' of this notion, and if not, can anyone suggest a correct one?

Comment: Can't you simply take $V=f(f^{-1}(U))$? Since $f^{-1}(U)$ is open and since the corestriction is a homeomorphism, $f^{-1}(U)$ corresponds to an open in $f(X)$, namely $V$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Indeed $V$ is open in $f(X)$ but that does not guarantee that it is open in $Y$ as is requested. E.g. let $f:X\to Y$ be the inclusion of a set $X\subseteq Y$ that is not open in $Y$. Then for $U=Y$ we find that $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(Y)=X$ is open in $X$. But $V=f(X)=X$ is not open in $Y$.

Comment: Ah you're right. I felt that I made a stupid mistake somewhere!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unraveling is correct.

$f$ is an embedding in category $\mathbf{Top}$ if $f$ is injective and secondly $X$ is equipped with the coarsest topology that makes $f$ continuous.

The second statement comes to the same as: $\tau_X=\{f^{-1}(V)\mid V\in\tau_Y\}$. So for every  $W\in\tau_X$  a set $V\in\tau_Y$ exists with $W=f^{-1}(V)$.

So if you start with some $U\subseteq Y$ and it appears that $f^{-1}(U)\in\tau_X$ then some $V\in\tau_Y$ exists with $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(V)$ or equivalently $U\cap\mathsf{im}f=V\cap\mathsf{im}f$.

---

This might interest you as well.

In the category $\mathbf{Top}$ a continuous mapping $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding if it is injective and **initial**.

The continuous mapping $f$ is initial if for every topological space $Z$ and every function $g:Z\to X$ continuity of $f\circ g$ implies continuity of $g$.